# Parse JSON into an array of objects

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have the following serialized class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Question
{
    public string question;
    public List<string> answers;
    public string correct;

    public Question(string question, List<string> answers, string correct){
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correct = correct;
    }
}
```

And the following array of `questions`:

```
questions = new List<GameManager.Question>();
questions.Add(new GameManager.Question("2+2?", new List<string> { "4", "5", "6" }, "4"));
questions.Add(new GameManager.Question("2*2?", new List<string> { "1", "4", "8" }, "4"));
questions.Add(new GameManager.Question("2/2?", new List<string> { "0", "1", "2" }, "1"));
```

I need to store this information as `json`format and load it to init the question game.

How I can load an array of questions using json?

Comment: You can use `NewtonSoft.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and  `Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` if you have that nuget package installed. Then just decorate your properties with a `JsonProperty` tag, documentation (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Comment: Have you tried looking online for C# libraries that allows you to work with JSON? If you haven't, you should do so before posing a question on Stack Overflow. If you have, you should explain what you've tried already, and why it hasn't met your requirements.

Comment: JsonUtility.ToJson(object) will convert your Question into a string in json format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use newtonsoft.json to serialize and deserialize the objects. It is very simple to use. I think you have to install the nuget package.

Here is a post on how to serialize and save data in unity 3d: [Post](http://naplandgames.com/blog/2016/11/27/saving-data-in-unity-3d-serialization-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example

```
void Main()
{
    var questions = new List<Question>();
    questions.Add(new Question("2+2?", new List<string> { "4", "5", "6" }, "4"));
    questions.Add(new Question("2*2?", new List<string> { "1", "4", "8" }, "4"));
    questions.Add(new Question("2/2?", new List<string> { "0", "1", "2" }, "1"));

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(questions, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Question
{
    public string question;
    public List<string> answers;
    public string correct;

    public Question(string question, List<string> answers, string correct)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correct = correct;
    }
}
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "question": "2+2?",
    "answers": [
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ],
    "correct": "4"
  },
  {
    "question": "2*2?",
    "answers": [
      "1",
      "4",
      "8"
    ],
    "correct": "4"
  },
  {
    "question": "2/2?",
    "answers": [
      "0",
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "correct": "1"
  }
]
```

You can deserialize it back to a collection of questions by

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Question[]>(json);
```

[image]

Comment: I need to generate a Question array from a json file, not generating a json file from that array.

Comment: @Lechucico Then you use `Newtonsoft.Json.DeserializeObject<T>` where T is a `List<Question>`, please see my answer or comment for documentation.

Comment: Updated @Lechucico

Comment: Thanks @AydinAdn. Any idea on how to import JsonConvert package on Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` if you have that `nuget package` installed. Then just decorate your properties with a `JsonProperty` tag, documentation (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)